# grub rescue after ububtu removing

Tags: 13.04, grub2

I've red plenty articles but i got no answer. 
i had improperly installed ubuntu 13.04 so i wanted to remove ubuntu from my hard drive. so through live cd -> gparted i removed everything linux partition and swap then formated both to ntfs. now i have this error. 
on the hdd was only the linux. nothing else.

ls output in grub rescue is (hd0,msdos1) .

set output is 
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boor/grub
root=hd0,msdos1

hopefully it will help and you would be able to help me.

cheers lama.

Answer (score 0):

You should install another `boot loader` and address your `MBR` or `UEFI` to the installed boot loader.

I assume you had a dual boot windows. In that case you can use windows installation cd to recovering your windows installation.

1. boot to installation media (cd, dvd, flash memory, etc)
2. go to recovery option (don't go to installation)
3. select reinstall `MBR` or `bootloader`
4. reboot

but you will miss ubuntu ;)